# Django error report emails - customize settings parameters

Tags: python, django, error-reporting

I noticed that the Django error report mails includes the settings parameters of my project, including some sensitive keys and secret numbers.

What is the best way of dropping/customizing some of the Django SETTINGS parameters out of the error report emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any setting with a name that contains API, TOKEN, KEY, SECRET, PASS or SIGNATURE will automatically be 'cleansed' (replaced with stars) in error mails. The easiest way to hide your own sensitive keys would probably be just renaming them.

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-sensitive-information) has some additional things you could do to obfuscate other sensitive data that can appear in error mails, like POST variables or traceback information.

Comment: Thats true for the django exception mails, but I get also "[Django] JS error" emails, which includes all the settings... what do I do about that?

Comment: I can't say I recognize the mails you're talking about - could it be that they are sent by an app you've installed, or by your own code perhaps?

Comment: yes, this emails comes from my own code (which I didn't write)... '_'
Thanks